# Why is there inequality $\langle\nabla{L(\gamma(t),t)},d_{t}\gamma(t)\rangle\geq|\nabla{L}|_{m}|d_{t}\gamma(t)|_{m}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality, partial-differential-equations

If $\alpha=\{\alpha_{i}\}$ amd $\beta=\{\beta_{j}\}$ are 1-froms and $s=\{s_{ij}\}$ is a symmetric positive definite covariant 2-tensor, we use the short notation, $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle_{s}=s_{ij}^{-1}\alpha_{i}\beta_{j}$, so $|\nabla{f}|_{h}^{2}=h_{ij}^{-1}\nabla_{i}f\nabla_{j}f$. there $\nabla$ is covariant derivative.

If $L=\log{k}$ is a continuous function of n-dimensional Euclidean space, $k=K^{\beta}，\beta>0$, $m=k^{-1}h_{ij}$, $K>0$ is Gaussian curvature and $h_{ij}$ is second basic form of convex surface, we have gradient estimate
$$\partial_{t}\log{k}-|\nabla\log{k}|^{2}_{m}\geq-[1+(n\beta)^{-1}]^{-1}t^{-1}$$

Integrating this estimate over paths in $M$(surface),
$$L(x_{2},t_{2})-L(x_{1},t_{1})=\int^{t_{2}}_{t_{1}}d_{t}(L(\gamma(t),t)dt
=\int^{t_{2}}_{t_{1}}(\partial_{t}L(\gamma(t),t)+\langle\nabla{L(\gamma(t),t)},d_{t}\gamma(t)\rangle)dt
\geq\int^{t_{2}}_{t_{1}}|\nabla{L}|^{2}_{m}-|\nabla{L}|_{m}|d_{t}\gamma(t)|_{m}-[1+(n\beta)^{-1}]^{-1}t^{-1}dt$$
$\gamma$ be any curve such that $\gamma(t_{i})=x_{i}$ for $i=1,2$,so why are there inequality

$$\langle\nabla{L(\gamma(t),t)},d_{t}\gamma(t)\rangle\geq|\nabla{L}|_{m}|d_{t}\gamma(t)|_{m}$$

Comment: Hi! I'd probably be helpful to clarify several things:
(1) what's $）$ (the rectangle symbol, maybe my browser is not rendering it properly, it's the thing next to $t_i$ is the second to last line.
(2) What is $m$? The notation is confusing. It is a function times a covariant 2-tensor, so I guess $m$ lacks indices? Is it simply another metric?

Comment: @topolosaurus thank you! I've revised it. For m, we have $|\nabla{L}|^{2}_{m}=Kh_{ij}^{-1}\nabla_{i}L\nabla_{j}L$.

Comment: @topolosaurus But I don't konw what $|\nabla{L}|_m$ means.